# array in foreach within class

Tags: php

I have a problem using an array within a foreach within a class. I get the warning..

> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

on line

```
foreach($this->recordOfDiscounts as $key => $discount)
```

The problematic function is below,

```
public function modify_price( $price, $product_id ) {
    foreach($this->recordOfDiscounts as $key => $discount) {
        foreach($discount['get_one_free'] as $id) {
            if($id == $product_id){
                if( $discount['valid'] > 0 ) {
                    $price -= $discount['cost'];
                    $this->recordOfDiscounts[$key]['valid'] -= 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $price;
}
```

I'm new to PHP, but what I've gathered is that the class scope (`$this->`) needs to prefix a var within a class.

```
error_log(print_r($this->recordOfDiscounts),0);
```

outputs the correct array info, so I know its defined.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [valid] => 1
            [buy_one] => 2351
            [cost] => 20
            [old_cost] => 20
            [get_one_free] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2471
                    [1] => 2470
                    [2] => 2472
                    [3] => 2473
                    [4] => 2474
                    [5] => 2475
                    [6] => 2476
                    [7] => 2477
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Where did you output to the error_log? Try outputting the contents of `$this->recordOfDiscounts` on the first line of your modify_price function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the foreach statements has something non-iterable as the first part of the statement.

Either `$this->recordOfDiscounts` is not an array, or on one iteration of the outer foreach, `$discount['get_one_free']` is not iterable.

Comment: sorry, i've edited the question to be more specific.The warning occurs on the line foreach($this->recordOfDiscounts as $key => $discount).